# Getting error when genrating the react-netive expo android app

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Hi any one help me out from this error in react-netive expo android code. getting below error..

Running "npm install" in /home/expo/workingdir/build directory

```
[stderr] npm
[stderr] ERR! code ERESOLVE
[stderr] npm
[stderr] ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
[stderr] npm ERR! 
[stderr] npm ERR! While resolving: @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.10
[stderr] npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
[stderr] npm ERR! node_modules/react
[stderr] npm ERR!   react@"17.0.2" from the root project
[stderr] npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @react-navigation/core@3.7.9
[stderr] npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/core
[stderr] npm ERR!     @react-navigation/core@"^3.7.9" from react-navigation@4.4.4
[stderr] npm ERR!     node_modules/react-navigation
[stderr] npm ERR!       react-navigation@"^4.x" from react-native-router-flux@4.3.1
[stderr] npm ERR!       node_modules/react-native-router-flux
[stderr] npm ERR!         react-native-router-flux@"^4.3.1" from the root project
[stderr] npm ERR!       3 more (react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-tabs)
[stderr] npm ERR!   23 more (react-dom, react-freeze, react-native, ...)
[stderr] npm ERR! 
[stderr] npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
[stderr] npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0" from @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.10
[stderr] npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view
[stderr] npm ERR!   @react-native-community/masked-view@"0.1.10" from the root project
[stderr] npm ERR!   peer @react-native-community/masked-view@">=0.1.0" from react-navigation-stack@2.10.4
[stderr] npm ERR!   node_modules/react-navigation-stack
[stderr] npm ERR!     react-navigation-stack@"^2.10.4" from the root project
[stderr] npm ERR!     1 more (react-native-router-flux)
[stderr] npm ERR! 
[stderr] npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
[stderr] npm ERR! node_modules/react
[stderr] npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.0" from @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.10
[stderr] npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view
[stderr] npm ERR!     @react-native-community/masked-view@"0.1.10" from the root project
[stderr] npm ERR!     peer @react-native-community/masked-view@">=0.1.0" from react-navigation-stack@2.10.4
[stderr] npm ERR!     node_modules/react-navigation-stack
[stderr] npm ERR!       react-navigation-stack@"^2.10.4" from the root project
[stderr] npm ERR!       1 more (react-native-router-flux)
[stderr] npm ERR! 
[stderr] npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
[stderr] npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
[stderr] npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
[stderr] npm ERR! 
[stderr] npm ERR! See /home/expo/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
[stderr] 
[stderr] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[stderr] npm ERR!     /home/expo/.npm/_logs/2023-06-14T17_05_01_166Z-debug-0.log
npm exited with non-zero code: 1
```

i am try code

```
npx expo start
```

also i have use one more command

```
expo build:android
```

but still getting error

Comment: can any one help me.?